# What is the Current Admin Password in Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento-enterprise, permissions, password

If I create a role, say "SAdmin" and give this role all the permissions as Magento Admin except permissions for Roles and Users - when Magento prompts for "Current Admin Password" when SAdmin is making changes, is this password that the SAdmin user logged in with or is it referring to the Administrator password?

Also, is the SAdmin able to perform all tasks except for creating users and Roles?

Answer (score 1):

When Magento prompts for `Current Admin Password`, it **prompts for the admin user password that is currently logged in**, not the one you're about to create. So if you're logged in to the backend as "SAdmin" it will be the "SAdmin" password.

Regarding your second question, the **role will have all the resources you've assigned it**. So if the role has all the permissions except for Roles & Users, it will indeed be able to perform all tasks except for accessing Users & Roles.

Comment: @Arv feel free to mark your question as answered so other people with the same question will benefit from yours

Comment: I created the role Super Admin & assigned all the permissions except for Role & Users.  When the user tries to Access CMS / Hooks, gets Access Denied.  So, had to change the role to Admin for this user to be able to access CMS / Hooks.  How can I resolve this?  Thanks for your help

Comment: @Arv where is that CMS / Hooks menu coming from ? Is that a 3rd party module ?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I was not involved during the installations with the developers.  Where do I check to verify if it's an added module or not.  It's one of the Tabs available on the Menu bar -->  CMS --> Pages, Static Blocks, Banners, Widgets, Polls, Hooks

Comment: @Arv definitely a custom module